# EBusError on assigning PageControl fpc/Lazaurs

Tags: windows-ce, arm, fpc, ttabsheet

I am trying to create dynamic TTabSheets for my program.
Written in FPC/Lazarus being built for ARM/WinCE
Everything works, including design time created tabsheets but the following code

```
try
  Tab      := TTabSheet.Create(PageControl1);
  logit('1');
  Tab.PageControl := PageControl1;
  logit('2');
  Tab.Caption := gname; 
except
  on E: Exception do
  begin
    logit(e.message);
    logit(e.classname);
  end;
end;
```

on the line *Tab.PageControl := PageControl1;* the exception *EBusError, Bus error or misaligned data access* is raised.

I Read this, but im not sure how it applies 
http://wiki.freepascal.org/Windows_CE_Development_Notes#Alignment_problems

the code works fine for win32
FPC Version 2.2.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After Some help from here
[http://lazarus.freepascal.org](http://lazarus.freepascal.org/index.php/topic,10217.msg50558.html)

The Answer was to use the Daily Snapshot, Lazarus-0.9.29-27140-fpc-2.4.3-20100819

All Fixed